# Clustering of wildfly using apache and haproxy

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, haproxy, jboss, wildfly8

There is a requirement from my boss to prepare a cluster of our application on wildfly application server.

I have designed the architecture as two haproxy(for loadbalancing),two apache servers for (ldap authentication) and two wildfly servers(hosting application).

I was confused whether may I may skip apache between haproxy and wildfly. Whether I can configure HAproxy with a Certification authority(SSL/TLS configuration) and ldap authentication.If these can be implemented at HAProxy level then putting apache between them will be useless and wastage of computing resources. Another confusion is that that LDAP authentication can be handled at both apache and wildfly,which option should I opt for?

Guys your valuable advice would be appreciated in this regards in improving the cluster architecture.

Comment: There is no need to delete and repost your questions. This is only confusing and can harm your account. Simply [improve the existing question](http://serverfault.com/help/no-one-answers).